# How to preserve element type validation upon adding custom element validation?

Tags: 8, forms

I have ConfigFormBase. 
It has a form element with `'#type' => 'entity_autocomplete'`.

**When I add my custom element validation** by `'#element_validate' => [[get_class($this), 'validateReferencedItemExistence']]` **the original element validation** which comes by the element type (`Drupal\Core\Entity\Element\EntityAutocomplete::validateEntityAutocomplete`) **won't be added anymore**.

After spending hours in the jungle of the `FormBuilder` class code I finally found the corresponding lines:

```
   if (isset($element['#type']) && empty($element['#defaults_loaded']) && ($info = $this->elementInfo->getInfo($element['#type']))) {
      // Overlay $info onto $element, retaining preexisting keys in $element.
      $element += $info;
      $element['#defaults_loaded'] = TRUE;
    }
```

I find this kinda bad approach, that you cannot extend the list of the validation items. What is the reason behind it?

**How could I make a workaround / solve this issue?**

(Just by calling `Drupal\Core\Entity\Element\EntityAutocomplete::validateEntityAutocomplete` in my custom validation I would create an unnecessary depedency in my code. (Just think about if they change their way of validation with a different function))

Comment: You need to use the syntax PHP has for adding items to an array. If you use `$array['item'] = [];` you are replacing `$array['item']`; if you use `$array['item'][] = [];` you are adding items (supposing that `$array['item']` is an array).

Comment: Am aware of that, however this is not the situation here, because if the key already exists, the element type validation won't be added anymore by the FormBuilder class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add the definitions defined in the getInfo() method of that type explicitly yourself, there is currently no other way to do that.